# Fast data writing to google spreadsheet from R

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I'm trying to write some data back to google spreadsheet from R Object (data frame to be specific), having around 42 columns and 1700 rows but looks like it is taking forever to write data back to google spreadsheet.

Is the currently config is not supporting this level of data writing back to google spreadsheet?

Comment: Perhaps you should give some information on how are writing to a google spreadsheet to start with.

Comment: apparently it's a known [issue](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/vignettes/basic-usage.html#add-a-new-worksheet-to-an-existing-google-sheet); have you found a solution?

Comment: No but given the details to the author of package.